# Why is this friend method not found as expected?

Tags: c++

When I have a small piece of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&);
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&) {
    os << "Called\n";
    return os;
}

class B {
public:
    operator A() { return A(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a;
    B b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

the `operator<<` is called twice for both `a` and `b`, because `b` has an implicit user conversion operator for type `A`. But I was surprised when I modified the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&) {
        os << "Called\n";
        return os;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    operator A() { return A(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a;
    B b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

As you see, I have just transferred the definition inside the class rather than using a free function and marking it as a `friend` of the class. But this code gives an error which says no suitable function for `operator<<` is found for `b`.

Why does this problem happen?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the process is, but I believe it's related to the name lookup process performed to generate candidate functions when evaluating `std::cout << b`. In your second code example, I don't think it looks inside the class definition of `A` for function declarations, but in the first it sees the function declaration (and definition) that occurs at file scope. When I place a line `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&);` after the definition of `A` but before `main`, it behaves as in the first code snippet, outputting "Called" twice.

Comment: @NathanPierson but cpp ref for my 2nd code says: *(only allowed in non-local class definitions) Defines a non-member function, and makes it a friend of this class at the same time. Such non-member function is always inline.* From this line, I assume that there should be no difference between these 2 codes.

Comment: btw, in the second code snippet, friend is irrelevant...

Comment: @mfnx it should be `friend` to be considered as non-member function. If not, it won't be called for even for `A`.

Comment: @Afshin No, Nathan is right. In your second example, if you're outside of class `A`, the `operator<<` can only ever be found by ADL. The `operator<<` is a non-member function, it is a `friend` of the `A`, and it is `inline` (so cppreference is not wrong) but it *also* has the unique property that if you don't give a declaration outside of `A` then you can only find it through ADL. I think the idea is that the `operator<<` is only defined within the scope of `A` (and ADL, when searching for things related to `A`, looks into that scope, so it can find it), but otherwise it's not in scope.

Comment: Can't say for sure without going through the standard, but I double down on previous comments: in the 2nd example the operator can only be found through adl

Comment: @HTNW hm....I decided to check ADL again to find out what happens. I found this sentence in ref: *namespace-scoped friend functions (and function templates) that are declared in an associated class are visible through ADL even if they are not visible through ordinary lookup.*. I thought this means these friend functions should be found, but I checked and noticed that if I add **only** declaration of `opeartor<<` to global scope, function will be found again. But it is somehow strange anyway, because it seems list of all these functions will be calculated for ADL and then discarded.

Comment: @HTNW in addition, I'm still not sure why ADL should find friend function for `A` in 2nd case.

Comment: Right. In the first code snippet, it doesn't need ADL to find `operator<<` because you've put a declaration at file scope. But in the second case where it would need to use ADL to find it, it can't `A` isn't one of the classes it checks during ADL. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl it looks for classes if the class is a base class of `B`, or a class that contains `B` as a member, or `B` itself. But none of those fit `A`, because "classes the class is implicitly convertible to" isn't actually on that list.

Comment: @NathanPierson I think you are right. If you add answer, I will set it as acceoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes down to how C++ generates candidate functions when performing overload resolution. It's trying to find candidates for `operator<<(std::cout, b)`. This means it performs [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) which includes performing [argument-dependent lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Let's take a look at how that works.

For the first code snippet, unqualified name lookup finds the declaration when it looks in the enclosing scope of the calling code, without needing to perform ADL. It sees `inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&)` as a candidate, and then is able to apply the user-defined conversion to `b` to see that it's a valid function to use for overload resolution. All well and good.

For the second code snippet, though, we don't have a declaration of `operator<<` at file scope. The declaration and definition are entirely within the definition of the class `A`. That still might let us find it as a candidate function for `std::cout << b`, but it'll have to be through ADL. Let's check to see if it's actually visible through that:

> Otherwise, for every argument in a function call expression its type
> is examined to determine the associated set of namespaces and classes
> that it will add to the lookup.
>
> ...
>
> 2. For arguments of class type (including union),
>    the set consists of
>
> a) The class itself
>
> b) All of its direct and indirect base classes
>
> c) If the class is a member of another class, the class of which it is a member
>
> d) The innermost enclosing namespaces of the classes added to the set

At any stage, would we look inside the definition of `A` when performing ADL with arguments `std::cout` and `b`? None of a), b), and c) apply to `A` because `A` isn't `B`, `A` isn't a base class of `B`, and `A` doesn't contain `B` as a member. Crucially, "any class to which the class is implicitly convertible" isn't used to generate candidates through ADL.

So ultimately in the second code snippet, the name lookup never sees the declaration of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&)` and never realizes that it can apply a user-defined conversion to apply it with the appropriate arguments.

If we just make the function declaration (not definition) visible at file scope like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&) {
        os << "Called\n";
        return os;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A&);

class B {
public:
    operator A() { return A(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a;
    B b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

This function declaration is once again found through ordinary unqualified name lookup, the user-defined conversion comes in during overload resolution, and the expected output of "Called" being printed twice is recovered.

Answer (score -3):

because you use friend only if you want access to the members of the class but still they need to defined as a global function and then make them friend function of the class.

Comment: it is somehow unrelated. You can always define body of friend function inside and you can see an example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/NullablePointer it is a common approach especially for operators.